# Parse inequality expressions (character) to numeric ranges

Tags: r

What is the proper way to obtain lower and upper extremes of inequality expression (character). Here is an example:

```
df = structure(list(expressions = c("x<1", "x>1", "x==1", "x<=1", 
"x>=1")), .Names = "expressions", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

My input is `df$expressions`. I want to obtain `df$minimum` and `df$maximum` like below

```
  expressions minimum maximum
1         x<1      NA 0.99999
2         x>1 1.00001      NA
3        x==1 1.00000 1.00000
4        x<=1      NA 1.00000
5        x>=1 1.00000      NA
```

When there is just `<`, subtract `1e-5` from the number. When there is just `>`, add `1e-5` to the number.

Comment: Why not writing a function that takes the inequality expression as character input and `x` as numeric input? As you said, `gsub` and `if ... else` do the trick.

Comment: You said: "When there is just <, subtract 1e-5 from the number." - so there is a number. There has to be a number to substract 1e-5...

Comment: Oh sorry, now I see. The "number" is 1, of course. Anyway, a simple function should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#FUNCTION
foo = function(eq, delta = 1e-5){
    #Extract the numerical portion of the expression
    n = as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", eq))

    #Create vector x
    x = c(-Inf, n - delta, n, n + delta, Inf)

    #Evaluate eq by plugging in x and subset values of x where TRUE
    y = x[eval(expr = parse(text = eq))]

    return(range(y))
}

t(sapply(df$expressions, foo))
#        [,1]    [,2]
#x<1     -Inf 0.99999
#x>1  1.00001     Inf
#x==1 1.00000 1.00000
#x<=1    -Inf 1.00000
#x>=1 1.00000     Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

An entire different approach that might not meet your requirements.
But I thought if in the end the goal is to use the ranges on actual data, you could actually also choose this approach.

If not, it was worth the try:

```
library(dplyr)

expressions = c('x < 1','x > 1','x == 1','x <= 1','x >= 1')

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0,2,by=1e-05))

df %>% mutate_(.dots=setNames(expressions, seq_along(expressions))) %>%
  gather(key,value, -x) %>% mutate(u = ifelse(value,x,NA)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>% summarise(minimum = min(u, na.rm=T), maximum = max(u, na.rm=T)) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, labels=expressions))
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     key minimum maximum
  <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  x < 1 0.00000 0.99999
2  x > 1 1.00001 2.00000
3 x == 1 1.00000 1.00000
4 x <= 1 0.00000 1.00000
5 x >= 1 1.00000 2.00000
```